# how to write datatable content into .xlsx file?

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable, xlsx

This is my code. It creates a xlsx file but takes 8 minutes to write cell by cell the contents of the datatable because it is composed of so many rows. Do you know an easier and faster way to insert the whole thing?

```
                   
                    Dim CootralimDettagli As New DataSet
                    CootralimDettagli = DB_SQL.OpenDataset("SELECT Anagrafica.CodiceSocio AS [Code Client], Anagrafica.Denominazione AS [Denominazione Socio], EU_VACON_10.ExternalOBUID, EU_VACON_10.PanNumber, EU_VACON_10.Targa AS Immatriculation, EuroClasse.ClasseVera AS [Classe Euro], EU_VACON_10.EntryDate AS [Date et heure], EU_TOLLCharger.Sigla AS Société, EU_STCon.Motorway AS [AUT ENTREE], EU_STCon.Denominazione AS [Libellé ENTREE], EU_STCon_1.Motorway AS [AUT SORTIE], EU_STCon_1.Denominazione AS [Libellé SORTIE], EU_VACON_10.AmountExcludedDiscount AS HT, EU_VACON_10.VATRate AS [%TVA], EU_VACON_10.AmountIncludingVAT AS TTC, EU_VACON_10.ExitGateCode, EU_VACON_10.Kilometers, Nazioni.Denominazione AS Nation FROM (((((EU_VACON_10 LEFT JOIN Anagrafica ON EU_VACON_10.ID_Cliente = Anagrafica.ID_cliente) LEFT JOIN EuroClasse ON EU_VACON_10.ID_Classe = EuroClasse.ID_Classe) LEFT JOIN EU_STCon ON EU_VACON_10.EntryGateCode = EU_STCon.GlobalGateIdentifier) LEFT JOIN EU_STCon AS EU_STCon_1 ON EU_VACON_10.ExitGateCode = EU_STCon_1.GlobalGateIdentifier) LEFT JOIN EU_TOLLCharger ON (EU_VACON_10.TSPNumber = EU_TOLLCharger.TspCode) AND (EU_VACON_10.TSPCountryCode = EU_TOLLCharger.CountryCode)) LEFT JOIN Nazioni ON EU_VACON_10.TSPCountryCode = Nazioni.ISO366 WHERE (((EU_VACON_10.ID_Cliente)=21189))", "Anagrafica.ID_cliente")

                    Try
                        Dim oExcel As Object
                        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
                        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
                        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
                        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
                        Dim oRange As Excel.Range
                        oSheet.Name = "Cootralim"

                        Dim DttDatiEsporta2 As DataTable = CootralimDettagli.Tables(0)

                        Dim rowCount As Integer = 1
                        For Each dr As DataRow In DttDatiEsporta2.Rows
                            rowCount += 1
                            For i As Integer = 1 To DttDatiEsporta2.Columns.Count
                                ' Add the header the first time through
                                If rowCount = 2 Then
                                    oSheet.Cells(1, i) = DttDatiEsporta2.Columns(i - 1).ColumnName
                                End If
                                oSheet.Cells(rowCount, i) = dr.Item(i - 1).ToString
                            Next
                        Next

                        ' Resize the columns
                        oRange = oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(1, 1),
                                  oSheet.Cells(rowCount, DttDatiEsporta2.Columns.Count))
                        oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

                        oBook.SaveAs("G:\Fatture PER Gruppi\2021\" + DataAlContrario + "\Cosar\Cosar_Cootralim.xlsx")
                        oBook.Close()
                        oBook = Nothing
                        oExcel.Quit()
                        oExcel = Nothing
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
```

Comment: Variant 1 - link SQL query to excel and just refresh it. Variant 2 - write cells like you do, but disable any calculations in Excel objects (and re-enable these before save!).

Comment: Use EPPlus/OpenXml/ClosedXml rather than automation